# Black screen after hibernation

Tags: arch-linux, macintosh, luks, hibernate, lvm

I have the problem described here:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#Hibernation

On the latest version of Arch Linux (4.7.5-1), on a mid-2012
MacBook Air (with LVM on LUKS), hibernation mostly works for me
but sometimes not.  It seemed that removing the `autodetect` hook
from mkinitcpio.conf helped some, I was able to hibernate and
resume several times, whereas with the hook only shortly after
rebooting; but sometimes I still see LUKS authentication followed by a
black screen.  This is not just the screen: I am unable to play
a sound or rehibernate using the power button.  I hesitate to
experiment with older kernels, as suggested in the linked article,
before hearing if anyone with a similar setup has a solution
already.  My `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` hooks:

```
HOOKS="base udev modconf block keyboard encrypt lvm2 resume filesystems fsck"
```

Comment: What is the question? This is a Q&A site so putting an interrogative sentence in your post, including question mark, is expected. And please don't ask a question like "Any ideas?", "Does someone have a solution for this problem?". Start with "How can I .....?" and then you have a good chance to make your post acceptable.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the same problem on Dell Vostro 1015